# Postfix : Only receive emails from specific tlds?

Tags: postfix, whitelist, tld

I've been searching everywhere and can only find how to block specific tlds.

I've set up a rejected_domains file that blocks tlds which I have to manually add as they appear in my inbox.

Basically, allow only .com, .net, .org, .gov, .edu... type domains.

With so many tlds out there now throwing spam, I'd prefer to have a whitelist of accepted tlds.

I do have checks in place like spamhuas and the like, also spamassaassin, but they still get through.

Comment: This has very little value in reducing spam. For most aplications of an email server, it does ensure that you will block legitimate emails. And you didn't say if the TLD related to the envelope/email or the connecting IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible by combining [`check_sender_access`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_sender_access) with [Postfix PCRE Support](https://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html).

Your default restriction would in this case be `reject`, but it might be better to add a human readable explanation on why the message was rejected.

In `main.cf` you would have something like the following. I usually place the [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) under the [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) because that would enable logging both the sender and the recipient, which is better for debugging.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,

    reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,

    check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/access/sender_access,
    reject
```

And in the `/etc/postfix/access/sender_access`, according to [pcre_table(5)](https://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html):

```
/\.net$/       OK
/\.org$/       OK
/\.gov$/       OK
/\.edu$/       OK
/\.([-\w]+)$/  550 The sender TLD .$1 is not whitelisted.
```

Here, I left the `.com` out because I wanted to demonstrate the results of this PCRE map:

```
$ /usr/sbin/postmap -q "user@example.net" pcre:/etc/postfix/access/sender_access
OK

$ /usr/sbin/postmap -q "user@example.com" pcre:/etc/postfix/access/sender_access
550 The sender TLD .com is not whitelisted.
```

Please notice that if you use `OK` in the `check_sender_access`, all other controls like the Spamhaus blocklist should come before it (as in the example above). Otherwise, mail from the whitelisted TLDs would come through even if, e.g., the IP address was blocked by the RBL. Using `DUNNO` instead of `OK` would allow other restrictions after it, but that would also require `permit` as the last rule (instead of `reject`).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Excellent explanation and examples. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad you found this useful. I have added a clarification regarding how this should be ordered with the Spamhaus blocklist & why.